# Jquery get the total height of x firsts elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to use tinker jquery plugin with dynamic height content.
I need to know the total height of the three firsts element, How can i calculate this?

```
<div class="myWrapper" ticker>
 <div>
   <div ng-repeat="latest in latests" class="latest">
      <p ng-bind-html="latest.txt"></p>
   </div> 
 </div>                   
</div>
```

my directive:

```
 restrict: 'A',
 link: function($scope, element) {

   var height = //I need the total height of the firsts three divs with class latest

         element.easyTicker({
            height: height',
            interval: 5000
         });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to let angular render the elements I would put the directive on the repeater and then you can check for the `$last` property within the `ng-repeat` child scope.

```
<div class="myWrapper">
 <div>
   <div ng-repeat="latest in latests" class="latest" ticker-item>
      <p ng-bind-html="latest.txt"></p>
   </div> 
 </div>                   
</div>
```

Directive

```
app.directive('ticker-item', function () {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function ($scope, element) {
        var height = 0;
        /* wait for last element in ng-repeat */
        if ($scope.$last) {
            element.siblings(':lt(3)').each(function () {
                height += $(this).height();
            });
            element.closest('.myWrapper').easyTicker({
                height: height,
                interval: 5000
            });
       }
    }
});
```

If the last element isn't being set properly by plugin, inject `$timeout` in directive and wrap plugin initialization in `$timeout()`. This will assure all of the repeater elements have been rendered first

Comment: But the ticker is works on the myWrapper childern and here you calc the children of tinker-item.

Comment: but with your markup it only has one child, a `<div>` which doesn't repeat

Comment: You can update the answer so i will mark it as the right answer please

Comment: siblings are not children of `latest`, they are `latest`

Answer (score 0):

```
restrict: 'A',
link: function($scope, element) {
var height = function () {
ii = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
ii += document.getElementsByClassName('latest')[i].style.height;
return ii;
};
element.easyTicker({
height: height,
interval: 5000
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
var el = $('.latest'), //your element
    heights = 0; //counter to be stored

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){ // adjust the "less than" to show how much to count
  heights += el.eq(i).height(); 
}

alert(heights);
```

```css
div { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="latest" style="height: 200px"></div>
<div class="latest" style="height: 150px"></div>
<div class="latest" style="height: 100px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Tinker, but I do know this is pretty easy to do in vanilla jQuery. For example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="example-wrapper">
     <!-- here are the children we care about -->
</div>
```

**Javascript / JQuery**

```
function count(){
    var height = 0;
    var count = 0;

    $("#example-wrapper").children().each(function(i){
        if(count < 3){
             height += $(this).height();
        }

        count += 1;
    });

    return count;
}
```

You can use the jQuery `each()` function to iterate through all the child elements of a element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery solution using slice() which is supposed to be more efficient than :lt(3)

```
function calcHeight(){
  var height = 0;
  $('.myWrapper .latest').slice(0, 2).each(function(){
    height += $(this).height();
  });
  return height;
}
```